# Special characters in LIKE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am looking to perform the following in SQL Server 2005 but I guess due to the character '#' the `LIKE` statement does not seem to be returning any result.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE keyword LIKE '%C#%'
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is no string in your table which contains "C#" this string.

Answer (score 2):

The only time you escape keywords in `LIKE` statement is when you are searching for `%`, `_`, and `[`. So that means `#` is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Must be something else. Check this [SQL Fiddle working code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b956/2) using `#` character

Answer (score 0):

`#` is fine in `LIKE`. Do you have any data that matches?

Comment: Yes, I found the problem sorry. The data stored in the database was not 'c#' but 'CZ0HashZ9' instead. Thanks for the help.